# Quantization for Single shot detector(SSD)

Tags: pytorch, object-detection, quantization, solid-state-drive, single-shot-detector

I have SSD model with good accuracy above 80per and detection will happen in 0.20 seconds.
However, I want to reduce the detection period to about 0.05-0.08seconds and reduce model size.

I came to know that quantization is the process to reduce the detection period.

Tried with post quantization, however it is not working as expected.

I want to perform quantization while training, which I'm not able to get any resources.
Can anyone suggest how to use quantization for Single shot detector model.